# Sumproduct with OR and Right function

Tags: excel, sumproduct

In column A are IDs like "1.23.1". The first and last numbers are the ones I use to identify the IDs I am looking for. The middle numbers range from 1 to 999, so IDs could be "1.1.1" OR "1.231.1. This information is only important to show that not all IDs have the same amount of characters.

I need to add the numbers from column B that match the IDs I am looking for.

```
A ----------- B
```

1.21.1 ------------5

1.314.2 ----------6

2.2.1 -------------3

I am getting a #VALUE! error with the following formula.
=SUMPRODUCT(OR((RIGHT(A4:A6,1)="1")+0,RIGHT(A4:A6,1)="2")+0,LEFT(A4:A6,1)="1",B4:B6

I would like to add the 5 and 6 because their IDs both end with 1 or 2 and start with 1.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg0iV.png)
[image]

Comment: Are the significant numbers in front and at the end of the ID string always single digit numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A4:A6)="1")*((RIGHT(A4:A6)="1")+(RIGHT(A4:A6)="2"))*B4:B6)
```

Using the `OR` function will only return a single value; hence your arrays will not be all the same length; hence the `#VALUE!` error.

Using addition will return an array of the `OR` test for each cell, instead of a single `OR` for the entire array.

If you want to use the function with separate arrays, where you convert each test array to it's numeric equivalent, (as in your example) you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(LEFT(A4:A6)="1"),N((RIGHT(A4:A6)="1")+(RIGHT(A4:A6)="2")),B4:B6)
```

[image]